# this._portalOutlet is undefined when trying to open a MatSnackBar

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to open a MatSnackBar when I catch an error. I've simplified it to this but I still can't get it to work.

```
constructor(public matSnackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    this.matSnackBar.open('test', 'Undo', {
        duration: 3000
    });
}
```

I keep getting the same error: `ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this._portalOutlet is undefined`.

I added `MatSnackBarContainer` to providers and entryComponents in my @NgModule

Comment: I wonder if you try to open in ngOninit you get the same error?

Comment: It is still the same, but with the page loaded obviously.

Comment: can you provide complete component code and try creating a demo to reproduce the issue in stackblitz?

Comment: I am facing the same issue with angular 8. tried exactly as in the angular.io tutorial, but get this error.

Comment: @VeeJay I solved it for myself. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by importing `MatSnackBarModule` along with providing `MatSnackBar` and adding `MatSnackBarContainer` to entryComponents

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSnackBarModule
  ],
  providers: [ MatSnackBar, {
    provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
    useValue: {}
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [MatSnackBarContainer]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```