# Angular Material Dialog "this._portalOutlet is undefined"

Tags: angular, angular-material

*Note: this is **not** a duplicate of [59054094](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054094/this-portaloutlet-is-undefined-when-trying-to-open-a-matsnackbar), the solution provided there does not work for me*

I tried using `MatDialog` from Angular Material as outlined in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples):

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dialog.open(DialogAnimationsExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
    })
  }
```

I use the `DialogAnimationsExampleDialog` from the documentation:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-animations-example-dialog',
  template: '`<h1 mat-dialog-title>Delete file</h1>\n' +
    '<div mat-dialog-content>\n' +
    '  Would you like to delete cat.jpeg?\n' +
    '</div>\n' +
    '<div mat-dialog-actions>\n' +
    '  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>No</button>\n' +
    '  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>\n' +
    '</div>\n`'
})
export class DialogAnimationsExampleDialog {
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogAnimationsExampleDialog>) {}
}
```

It compiles successfully, but I get the following error message in the browser console:

> ERROR TypeError: this._portalOutlet is undefined
> Angular 3
> ngOnInit app.component.ts:15

### Module definitions

I tried the following set of definitions, all resulting in the same error message

#### 1. my initial approach

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppComponent, DialogAnimationsExampleDialog} from './app.component';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogContainer, MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogAnimationsExampleDialog
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

#### 2. After reading [59054094](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59054094/this-portaloutlet-is-undefined-when-trying-to-open-a-matsnackbar)

```js
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {AppComponent, DialogAnimationsExampleDialog} from './app.component';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogContainer, MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DialogAnimationsExampleDialog
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MatDialog,
    {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
      useValue: {}
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [MatDialogContainer]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

#### Replacing onInit()

as @EdmundsFolkmanis suggested, the error might be related to incomplete component initialization. So I placed the call to `this.dialog.open()` in a separate method, which gets triggered by a click-event on a simple button:

```js
// app.component.ts
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogAnimationsExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
    })
  }
```

```html
<!--app.component.html-->
<button (click)="openDialog()">
  open
</button>
```

However, apart from the stacktrace, the error prevails unchanged.

Comment: Why are you opening dialog already in ngOnInit when component initialization is not fully completed? Usually dialog is opened as a response to some event.

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis To keep the example more simple. When I create a button with a simple click-event leading to a method opening the dialog, the error still prevails

Comment: What Angular version are you using? Adding component to `entryComponents` is not necessary from version 10 or so. This will definitely not solve the problem.

Comment: 'providers' array in NgModule looks strange. `MatDialog` service is provided on MatDialogModule import, and MAT_DIALOG_DATA is provided on MatDialog#open. They don't have to appear there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by upgrading angular from version 14 to 15.